# nodejs assert module: assert.throws only returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert

As found in the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message). Trying the below code would only result in 
`undefined`.

```js
assert.throws(
  () => {
    throw new Error('Wrong value');
  },
  Error
);
```

I was able to find some issues about the arrow functions `=>` not working in the statement but changing that to `function()` doesn't change a thing. As in the link above my node version is the exact same version.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

```js
console.log(assert.throws(
  () => {
    throw new Error('Wrong value');
  },
  Error
)) // this will log "undefined"

let result = assert.throws(
  () => {
    throw new Error('Wrong value');
  },
  Error
);

console.log(result); // as well as this
```

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _returns_ undefined?

Comment: @tkausl I'm sorry I did not add to the code snippet. rapping the statement in ```console.log(...)``` or assigning it to a variable is what I mean't.

Comment: asserts are not supposed to return anything.

Comment: @tkausl If that is the case, what on earth is ```assert.throws``` suppose to do?

Comment: It asserts that the passed function throws.

Comment: @tkausl Ah, so it will throw an error when the passed function does not throw an ```Error```. Made sense. Thanks. BTW, would you know any function that would help me check whether something throws an error returning a boolean...? or am I left to use try catch?

Answer (score 0):

So, as [@tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl) has stated in the comments (thanks by the way.) `assert.throws` "asserts that the passed function throws".

In order to achieve my desired result, I had to do this:

```js
console.log(() => {
    let error;
    try {
        // function that may throw an error
    } catch (e) {
        error = e;
    }
    // and than do something with 'error' and return a value
    return error
}())
```